# Show/Hide header/divider with the scrollbar position inside a listview

Tags: android, listview, dialog, android-dialogfragment, android-scrollbar

I have an alert dialog which has a list of single choice radio buttons. How can I achieve a behavior where the header divider is hidden when scrolled to bottom, footer divider is hidden when scrolled to top and both header/footer visible when the scrollbar hangs in between.

Something similar to the "Phone ringtone" selecter in Nexus

1. Scrolled to top

[image]

2. Scrolled to bottom

[image]

3. In the middle

[image]

Comment: look to my answer if you using custom view in alert dialog
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49916910/4565842