# Divider line in dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I noticed something very useful in Google apps.

When we have dialog with big content, divider line is showing in order to emphasize ability to scroll, like in this two pictures:

[image: first][image: second]

But, I have no idea how to implement such behaviour using known utils.

Best example is while choosing phone ring, at the start there is only divider on the bottom, but when we start scrolling two dividers appear.

[image]

**QUESTION**

How to implement appearing and disappearing behaviour in dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour that you want to achieve comes with a `Dialog with Scrollable Content`. Please read [this document](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-behavior) to get an idea of that.

In this case, you need to create your own custom layout xml with `ListView` and couple of buttons. And you need to keep this entire layout under `ScrollView`.

The following is just a dummy code to help you with:

**Edited the dummy code with the actual one::**

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ListView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.class:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater= LayoutInflater.from(this);
    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, null);
    ListView listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    String[] items = { "Milk", "Butter", "Yogurt", "Toothpaste", "Ice Cream" };
    ArrayAdapter adapter_dest = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter_dest);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Custom Dialog")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setView(view)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You mean wrapping everything in ScrollView will add automatically divider line?

Comment: Yes, that's what I could get from the document. Scrolling the content keeping the title as fixed.

Comment: Title will be fixed, but remember that I'm asking for grey divider lines, and I'm trying to achieve that by wrapping everything with scroll view but it's not working

Comment: @ThirdMartian -- I have edited the previous dummy code with a actual one. I have created a custom layout with a `ListView` which is scrollable by default. Without scrolling it does not give the divider lines, but with scrolling it DOES give an effect of it. Please check my edited answer, and then let me know what needs to be improved from there. :)

Comment: This may work with a ListView, but it doesn't with a scrollView

Comment: This code doesn't work at all, the divider is not shown

Answer (score 1):

If you have custom layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/views_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</ScrollView>
```

you can inflate View and find ScrollView by

```
v.findViewById(R.id.scroll_container)
```

and set scroll TOP and BOTTOM indicators if you have TITLE above and BUTTONS below your custom view

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        final int indicators = View.SCROLL_INDICATOR_TOP | View.SCROLL_INDICATOR_BOTTOM;
        scrollView.setScrollIndicators(indicators, View.SCROLL_INDICATOR_TOP | View.SCROLL_INDICATOR_BOTTOM);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Android source code the solution is really simple. Just add this code to your custom view:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
   final int indicators = (hasTopPanel() ? View.SCROLL_INDICATOR_TOP : 0)
              | (hasBottomPanel() ? View.SCROLL_INDICATOR_BOTTOM : 0);
   view.setScrollIndicators(indicators, View.SCROLL_INDICATOR_TOP | View.SCROLL_INDICATOR_BOTTOM);
}
```

Comment: what is the "hasBottomPanel()" method?